# View Google Sketchup (.skp) files on the web (Rehash)

Tags: silverlight, flash, canvas, sketchup

Can anyone point me to any libraries or products that will allow me to pass a Google Sketchup SKP file in and as a result view the 3D model on a website in either Silverlight, Flash or HTML Canvas?

I know both Flash & Silverlight now support 3D out of the box, so I'm hoping there has been some updates since answers below were given over a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight's still kinda slow as far as web 3d engines are concerned (although I'm expecting great things from it in the next few years).

So in flash there's alot of evolved graphic engines like Papervision3D for example. You use these libraries to load a certain 3d file format, I forgot the name.

Anyway, you then just export your sketchup file into this format, or into another format you could later convert. Although I think you need the FULL version of sketchup to export if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Sketchup can export to COLLADA which than can be loaded into Silverlight and than displayed using the ViewPort3d control.. i'm not 100% but i will post back when i have an answer.. i believe Silverlight 3 has this control only

Comment: @Chris: any luck figuring out a good way to import your 3D models?

Comment: Hi Dave, i downloaded the new Sketchup version which allows you to export to COLLADA. I then found some source code for displaying a COLLADA file in WPF which I believe will work for silverlight 3. http://blogs.msdn.com/guillaumerandon/archive/2006/08/29/729841.aspx you'll have to navigate your way through the non english version to find the source just look for the heading. Good luck

Comment: why Flash is going down? does any one have answer/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as [3DPaintBrush](http://www.3dpaintbrush.com/blogs/3dpaintbrush/archive/2008/09/02/create-2d-3d-xaml-from-3d-models.aspx) to export the Sketchup files to XAML which can then be used in Silverlight projects. Unfortunately 3DPaintBrush isn't free, but it does have a 15 day trial to see if it is worth getting.

Comment: I've looked into 3DPaintBrush.. maybe i haven't researched enough.. but from what i did see it will not work for what i'm aiming to do.. I want to load in my model and have it working with out having to convert into XAML etc etc..